# RSA java encrypt .net decrypt

Tags: c#, rsa

How to convert a java keystore( eg test.jks) to a .net key container?

I am using the following link as reference 
http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/dotnet/RSAEncrypt/index.html

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far? And what problems you are running into?

Comment: I think its not constructive  when you find a whole source there, to discuss here.